# How to set an arraylist item to a JButton

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jbutton

I'm making a game where questions are asked and the players answers them by selecting one of four buttons. I have two classes, one which is 'QuestionsAndButtons' and the other is 'Main'. I want to get an element from my arraylist of strings in the 'QuestionsAndButtons' class and display it onto a JButton in my 'Main' class.

When the 'generalknowledge' button is clicked, I want to set the arraylist item to the JButton 'option1'.

Main class:

```
   generalKnowledge.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Categories1.setVisible(false);
                GeneralKnowledge1.setVisible(true);

                String q = quest.getAQuestion(0);
                question1.setText(q);

                String b1 = quest.getButtons(0);
                option1.setText(b1);
            }
        });
```

QuestionsAndButtons class:

```
private ArrayList<String> buttonsGK1;

public  QuestionsAndButtons(){

    questionsGeneralKnowledge=new ArrayList<>();
    buttonsGK1=new ArrayList<>();

    buttonsGK1.add("Eeyore");
    buttonsGK1.add("Tigger");
    buttonsGK1.add("Piglet");
    buttonsGK1.add("Rabbit");

}

public String getButtons(int j) {
    return buttonsGK1.get(j);
}
```

Also, everytime I run my code I get this error as soon as I click the 'generalknowledge' button:

*Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out-of-bounds for length 0*

Comment: What you're trying to do is have 4 options, each of them displayed in their own `JButton` am I right?

Comment: Yesss that's exactly what I'm trying to do

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some of your variable are correct, others are not. Be consistent!!!

Comment: For the exception you get, we need to see a [mcve] to know what exactly is happening

Comment: If you see `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` for index 0, then the array or list is empty when you try to access the element. Use a debugger and check if the array/list you access is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to create a `JButton` with each option from the array is:

1. Create an array of `JButton`s of the same length of your options
2. Iterate over your options and create a new `JButton` with the text of the options
3. Add each `JButton` to the `JPanel` / `JFrame` you're working with

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ArrayToButtons {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel pane;
    private JButton[] buttons;
    private static final String[] OPTIONS = {"Eagle", "Rabbit", "Dolphin", "Apple"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ArrayToButtons()::createAndShowGui);
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());
        pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));

        buttons = new JButton[OPTIONS.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new JButton(OPTIONS[i]);
            pane.add(buttons[i]);
        }

        frame.add(new JLabel("Which is not an animal?"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your answer @Frakcool but I already have an interface as I am using GUI form so all I wanted was an easy way to set one of the answers from my arraylist to my JButton 'option1'.

Is there a way to go about this?

[Here is what the UI looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hT2Qs.jpg)

Comment: 1) This could have been a comment to my answer, or and edit to your question, as this is not an answer. 2) *"all I wanted was an easy way to set one of the answers from my arraylist to my JButton 'option1'"* I already showed you how to do it with an array, change the array for an arraylist and you're done... 3) If you want us to check your GUI code you must provide a [mcve] then

Answer (score 0):

Put your buttons in an array or a List, then iterate over both button array and title array and set the title:

```
JButton buttons[];
List<String> titles = quest.getButtons();

for (int i = 0; i < titles.size(); i++) {
    buttons[i].setText(titles.get(i));
}
```

where quest.getButtons() returns `buttonsGK1` field in your sample.

You need to initialize `buttons` array when you create your GUI. [Frakcool's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49178863/572834) shows all these aspects, you just need to adopt the solution to your own case.